# How to create an all powerful god-like character with real flaws and weakness?

Tags: fiction, creative-writing, character-development

The protagonist of my story is an all-powerful do gooder superhuman. She is like Wonder Woman and Amélie merged and She could literally get things done by thinking about them. She was raised by a single mother who lost her husband trying to save their newborn child.

She is later introduced to her immense powers in her adolescence but has to go through a lot to master them for years. This, coupled with her humble upbringing, makes her wise and kind.

As you can see that this character looks like it could do no wrong and so I have run into the problem of not being able to create real conflicts for her. I suppose there would be a few characters in fiction and in history with similar backdrops. Can anyone refer me materials which have similar character/s which I can study to refine my protagonist.

**Edit :** Her powers do not include ability to turn back time or read minds or omnipresence. But she has strength to move mountains, can teleport, manipulate environment and create things by thinking about them

Comment: Hi @shashank and welcome to Writers. This question is asking us to help you generate ideas, which is off topic here. We are about helping you express the ideas you already have. To learn more about how things work here, please take the tour: https://writers.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: I wrote a giant answer, but didn't manage to post it before the question was put on hold (sigh). Making it short, look up Dr. Manhattan.

Comment: This would depend upon opinion, specifically what is meant by "all powerful". If a character is immortal and can rewind time, they have no weakness. If they are also omniscient and know every thought and feeling of their putative 'opponent' and exactly what will happen (the power of knowing), they have no weakness. Even a lack of imagination cannot be a weakness, it suggests they do not have a useful power. You have to constrain "all powerful" in some way, and an opponent finding a way to exploit that constraint produces their weakness. Perhaps they cannot rewind time, or are not omniscient.

Comment: To get ideas for her, consider: Where are the biggest regrets in **your** life, or in the lives of people you know? What sorts of failings in public figures are most troubling to you? <-- She needs to be human in some way, with human foibles. She can be all powerful, and still have her achille's heel, based on some human trait. How does she feel about being responsible (in a sense) for her father's death?

Comment: @FFN Just a question, did you create [this chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68962/on-god-like-characters) with this question in mind? Two of us over on WorldBuilding discovered it and thought the title sounded interesting. You could post your answer there if you still have the draft lying around.

Comment: @Secespitus, yes I did, but gave up halfway through and thought it had not been created. Weird. I created it exactly for the draft, but now is way too late